# Detecting the piano notes using python

Tags: audio, python, audio-processing, pitch

I am trying to build a small application that is very similar to simply piano, where I am trying to detect the piano notes, my program will be listening and when a key gets pressed it will estimate the pitch of the sound wave and map it to the nearest key that is mapped. I am currently using [Parselmouth](https://github.com/YannickJadoul/Parselmouth) for this task, it works well when there is only one key press, but I am having a hard time detecting when two or more keys are pressed together.

this https://soundcloud.com/brahma-reddy-229290077/piano-key-notes-c3-c4 is the sound that I am experimenting with it is a recording of 3rd and 4th-octave C notes

find the plot after detecting the pitch of these notes pitch detection

```
def draw_pitch(pitch):
 # Extract selected pitch contour, and
 # replace unvoiced samples by NaN to not plot
 pitch_values = pitch.selected_array['frequency']
 pitch_values[pitch_values==0] = np.nan
 plt.plot(pitch.xs(), pitch_values, 'o', markersize=5, color='w')
 plt.plot(pitch.xs(), pitch_values, 'o', markersize=2)
 plt.grid(False)
 plt.ylim(0, pitch.ceiling)
 plt.ylabel("fundamental frequency [Hz]")

pitch = snd.to_pitch()
# If desired, pre-emphasize the sound fragment before calculating the spectrogram
pre_emphasized_snd = snd.copy()
pre_emphasized_snd.pre_emphasize()
spectrogram = pre_emphasized_snd.to_spectrogram(window_length=0.03, maximum_frequency=8000)
plt.figure()
draw_spectrogram(spectrogram)
plt.twinx()
draw_pitch(pitch)
plt.xlim([snd.xmin, snd.xmax])
plt.show() # or plt.savefig("spectrogram_0.03.pdf")
```

Output

[image]
here when both the C keys are pressed together the pitch is coming around 260 which is the same as when the first C of the 3rd octave is pressed.

how can I detect the keys that are pressed, please help me if there are any applications of signal processing or machine learning to solve this task.

Comment: Pitch detection is a kinda tough nut.  Monophonic (single note) pitch detection is pretty doable, but polyphonic (mult-inote) pitch detection is damn hard (because it involves the same problem as source separation) and I dunno how Melodyne does it so well. If you play the high C at 520 Hz, that means that the periodic waveform repeats every 1/520th second. But that means it *also* repeats every 1/260th second.  So the high C is just like middle C except it only has even-numbered harmonics. So, when you're looking for a period, you need to find the smallest period. This is the "octave problem".